# Overloaded Methods in a class (arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

Header code

```
/*
 * MngCommunication.h
 *
 *  Created on: 26 gen 2017
 *      Author: Giuliano
 */

#ifndef _MNGCOMMUNICATION_H_
#define _MNGCOMMUNICATION_H_

// ------------------------- N.B. MngCommunication is a Singleton     class!!! ----------------------------
#if (ARDUINO <  100)
#include <WProgram.h>
#else
#include <Arduino.h>
#endif

class MngCommunication
{
public:
    static MngCommunication* getInstance();


    size_t LogLine(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const String &str, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const char str[], boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const unsigned char n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const int n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const unsigned int n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const long n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const unsigned long n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const double n, boolean end=false);
    size_t LogLine(const Printable&str, boolean end=false);

protected:
    static MngCommunication* _inst_;
    MngCommunication();
};

#endif /* MNGCOMMUNICATION_MNGCOMMUNICATION_H_ */
```

C++ code

```
/*
 * MngCommunication.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 26 gen 2017
 *      Author: Giuliano
 */

#include <string.h>
#include "MngCommunication.h"


MngCommunication* MngCommunication::_inst_ = NULL;


MngCommunication::MngCommunication()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);

}


MngCommunication* MngCommunication::getInstance()
{
    if (_inst_ == NULL) _inst_ = new MngCommunication;

    return _inst_;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------ LOGGING FUNCTION -------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
boolean started=false;

inline size_t startLine(void)
{
    static char timebuffer[8];
    size_t sz = 0;

    sprintf(timebuffer,"%08lu", millis());

    sz += Serial.print("#L-");
    sz += Serial.print(timebuffer);
    sz += Serial.print("-");
    started=true;
    return sz;

}

inline size_t endline(void)
{
    started = false;
    return Serial.write("\r\n");
}

size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh, boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
    sz += startLine();
    started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(ifsh);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }


    return sz;
}

size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const String &str, boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(str);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
}


size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const char str[], boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(str);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
}





size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const unsigned char n, boolean end)
{
    return LogLine((unsigned long) n, end);
}


size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const int n, boolean end)
{
    return LogLine((long) n, end);
}

size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const unsigned int n, boolean end)
{
    return LogLine((unsigned long) n, end);
}


size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const long n, boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(n);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
 }

 size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const unsigned long n, boolean end)
 {
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(n);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
}



size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const double n, boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
     }

     sz += Serial.print(n);

    if (end)
    {
         sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
}

size_t MngCommunication::LogLine(const Printable&str, boolean end)
{
    size_t sz=0;
    if (!started)
    {
        sz += startLine();
        started = true;
    }

    sz += Serial.print(str);

    if (end)
    {
        sz += endline();
    }

    return sz;
}
```

If I use `LogLine()` function with string or char buffers, all is OK. e.g.:

```
MngCommunication* Comm;

Comm = MngCommunication::getInstance();
Comm.LogLine("this ");
Comm.LogLine("is ");
Comm.LogLine("a ");
Comm.LogLine("test!!! ", true);
```

The strange is the call with number:
if i call  `LogLine()` with number e.g.:

```
MngCommunication* Comm;

Comm = MngCommunication::getInstance();
Comm.LogLine(millis());
```

code execution is OK. but a second call, with number or string, reboot Arduino. The same is if i call the function first with string and then with number. e.g.:

```
MngCommunication* Comm;

Comm = MngCommunication::getInstance();
Comm.LogLine("this ");
Comm.LogLine("is ");
Comm.LogLine("a ");
Comm.LogLine("test!!! ");

Comm.LogLine("time= ");
Comm.LogLine(mills());
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Does this happen for **all** of the different overloaded 'number' functions (i.e. double, long, int, etc.)?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ
Arduino haven't a line-by-line debugger...
I'm work on other platform, cross compiler or machine compiler and in those case i use normally the line-by-line debugger. But on Arduino i can't.

Comment: @Archimaredes 
Yes! I've tryed with different number format.

Comment: @Archimaredes 
Yes! I've tryed with **all** different number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static char timebuffer[8];
sprintf(timebuffer,"%08lu", millis());
```

First of all this buffer is too small. There has to be space for the string terminator (zero byte), so you have a buffer overflow which can cause all sort of strange effects.

This buffer should be at least 11 bytes long. 10 bytes for the max number (32 bit) and one for the string terminator.

I suppose `mills()` was a typo?

Do you have the same problem when using a constant value, like `Comm.LogLine(123);`?

And what if you call:

```
Comm.LogLine(123, true);
Comm.LogLine(456);
```

Comment: Yes, I'd the same effect with constant value.
`millis()` is an Arduino function that return the long (unsigned 32bit) milliseconds since the board is started.

Comment: The winner is....

`static char timebuffer[9]`

snort!! I don't understand why only when I'm using the numbers, nor the string. I suppose for a different management by the `Serial.print()`. I'm very tired today!

Comment: Hard to predict what can or will happen with buffer overflow (mostly strange things where you least expect them). Have a good rest! :) -- `millis()` yes, but you were calling `mills()` in the examples.

Comment: And don't forget to change that value to at least 11 (not 9), or you'll have the same (or another!) problem when you leave the Arduino on for more than 27.8 hours.

Comment: Yes! I've changed! Also the lenght in `sprintf()` placeholder.
`mills()` is a typo, but only in Stack Overflow code...